# How to parse each line of a text file as an argument to a command?

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I'm looking to write a script that takes a `.txt` filename as an argument, reads the file line by line, and passes each line to a command. For example, it runs `command --option "LINE 1"`, then `command --option "LINE 2"`, etc. The output of the command is written to another file. How do I go about doing that? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `while read` loop:

```
: > another_file  ## Truncate file.

while IFS= read -r line; do
    command --option "$line" >> another_file
done < file
```

Another is to redirect output by block:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    command --option "$line"
done < file > another_file
```

Last is to open the file:

```
exec 4> another_file

while IFS= read -r line; do
    command --option "$line" >&4
    echo xyz  ## Another optional command that sends output to stdout.
done < file
```

If one of the commands reads input, it would be a good idea to use another fd for input so the commands won't eat it (here assuming `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash` for `-u 3`, use `<&3` instead portably):

```
while IFS= read -ru 3 line; do
    ...
done 3< file
```

Finally to accept arguments, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
another_file=$2

exec 4> "$another_file"

while IFS= read -ru 3 line; do
    command --option "$line" >&4
done 3< "$file"
```

Which one could run as:

```
bash script.sh file another_file
```

Extra idea. With `bash`, use `readarray`:

```
readarray -t lines < "$file"

for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Note: `IFS=` can be omitted if you don't mind having line values trimmed of leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 48):

Another option is `xargs`.

With GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -a file -I{} -d'\n' command --option {} other args
```

`{}` is the place holder for the line of text.

Other `xargs` generally don't have `-a`, `-d`, but some have `-0` for NUL-delimited input. With those, you can do:

```
< file tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I{} command --option {} other args
```

On Unix-conformant systems (`-I` is optional in POSIX and only required for UNIX-conformant systems), you'd need to preprocess the input to *quote* the lines in the format expected by `xargs`:

```
< file sed 's/"/"\\""/g;s/.*/"&"/' |
  xargs -E '' -I{} command --option {} other args
```

However note that some `xargs` implementations have a very low limit on the maximum size of the argument (255 on Solaris for instance, the minimum allowed by the Unix specification).

Comment: reducible to `<file xargs -L 1 -I{} command --option {} other args`

Comment: @iruvar, no, that would process quotes and remove some blanks.

Answer (score 13):

Keeping precisely to the question:

```
#!/bin/bash

# xargs -n param sets how many lines from the input to send to the command

# Call command once per line
[[ -f $1 ]] && cat $1 | xargs -n1 command --option

# Call command with 2 lines as args, such as an openvpn password file
# [[ -f $1 ]] && cat $1 | xargs -n2 command --option

# Call command with all lines as args
# [[ -f $1 ]] && cat $1 | xargs command --option
```

Answer (score 10):

The best answer I found is:

```
for i in `cat`; do "$cmd" "$i"; done < $file
```

**EDIT:**

... four years later ...

after several down votes and some more experience I'd recommend the following now:

```
xargs -l COMMAND < file
```

Comment: This will invoke the command once for each ***word*** in the file.  Also, you should always quote references to shell variables (as in `do "$cmd" "$i";`) unless you have a reason not to; if the file contained a `*` as a word by itself, your code would run `$cmd *`, which, of course, would run the command with a list of the files in the current directory.

Comment: @G-Man, except in `zsh`, the `\`cat\`` would already expand the `*` (the unquoted `$i` could still expand some wildcard (a second round) if the expansion of `\`cat\`` introduces some). In any case, that approach is wrong indeed.

Comment: +1. This will work fine, if each line contains only the input needed for the command being used without spaces.

Comment: This acts on each word, is there a variant of this that acts on each line?

Comment: The question was to process a list of filenames line by line.

Comment: This is working! (the later edit `xargs -l COMMAND < file`). Thanks!

Comment: An enhancement for when you need more than 1 argument: `xargs -l -a files.txt -i echo begin {} end`. In my case I needed to mv the files in the .txt to another dir

Answer (score 2):

```
    sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/.*/\$* '&'/" <<\FILE |\
    sh -s -- command echo --option
all of the{&}se li$n\es 'are safely shell
quoted and handed to command as its last argument
following --option, and, here, before that echo
FILE
```

#### OUTPUT

```
--option all of the{&}se li$n\es 'are safely shell
--option quoted and handed to command as its last argument
--option following --option, and, here, before that echo
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ed file.txt
%g/^/s// /
2,$g/^/-,.j
1s/^/command/
wq
chmod 755 file.txt
./file.txt
```

Take all the lines of a file and pass them as arguments to a single command i.e.,

```
command line1 line2 line3 ....
```

If you need the `--option` flag to precede each line change the second command to:

```
%g/^/s// --option /
```

Comment: What -1 for using ed...really?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the person who did probably had these reasons: (1) This doesn’t do what the question asks for.  This invokes the command once with all the contents of the file on the command line; rather than *once per line*.  (2) This does nothing to handle characters that are special to the shell (that might be in the file); e.g., `'`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `;`, etc.  (3) This creates an unnecessary temporary file.  (4) Things like this are generally done with “here documents”.  (5) Your `ed` commands are clumsy; the first two commands can be reduced to `%s/^/ /` and `%j`.