# How to pass every line of a file as options to a command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, arguments, options

I'd like to write a script that reads a file and passes every line as options (or "option arguments") to a command, like this:

```
command -o "1st line" -o "2nd line" ... -o "last line" args
```

What's the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass each line of a text file as an argument to a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149726/how-to-pass-each-line-of-a-text-file-as-an-argument-to-a-command)

Comment: No, it's not, sorry

Comment: I'd modify the program to accept just the file name/full path as input and have it read the file in itself....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
$ cat tmp
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
4th line
$ command $(sed 's|.*|-o "&"|' tmp | tr '\n' ' ')
```

As glennjackman points out in the comments, word splitting can be circumvented by wrapping in eval, though the [security implications](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) of doing so should be appreciated:

```
$ eval "command $(sed 's|.*|-o "&"|' tmp | tr '\n' ' ')"
```

**Edit:** Combining my suggestion of using `sed` to assemble arguments  with glenn jackman's `mapfile`/`readarray` approach gives the following concise form:

```
$ mapfile -t args < <(sed 's|.*|-o\n&|' tmp) && command "${args[@]}"
```

As a trivial demonstration, consider the aforementioned `tmp` file, the command `grep`, and the file `text`:

```
$ cat text
some text 1st line and
a 2nd nonmatching line
some more text 3rd line end
$ mapfile -t args < <(sed 's|.*|-e\n&|' tmp) && grep "${args[@]}" text
some text 1st line and
some more text 3rd line end
$ printf "%s\n" "${args[@]}"
-e
1st line
-e
2nd line
-e
3rd line
-e
4th line
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not maintain the lines as whole elements due to the shell's [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting). Try where the command is `printf "%s\n"` -- instead of receiving 8 arguments (`-o` `1st line` ...), this technique will give the command **12 arguments** containing literal quote chars (`-o` `"1st` `line"` `-o` `"2nd` `line"` etc). You *could* do `eval "command $(sed ...)"` but that's nasty and fragile.

Comment: @glennjackman: Agreed, `eval` would be needed to avoid the word splitting problem; your command array-based approach is better for general use.

Answer (score 5):

```
# step 1, read the lines of the file into a shell array
mapfile -t lines < filename

# build up the command
cmd_ary=( command_name )
for elem in "${lines[@]}"; do
    cmd_ary+=( -o "$elem" )
done
cmd_ary+=( other args here )

# invoke the command
"${cmd_ary[@]}"
```

Comment: This.  Although you'll want to maybe check the file for total number of lines (or other delimiter) so that you don't call your command with more arguments than it can handle - might want to read up on this (old) article and then check for newer references - https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/